# How to configure 2 VirtualHost from Apache2: one with Documentroot and one with Proxypass?

Tags: apache2, jupyter, virtualhost, moodle, proxypass

I am configuring apache2 on a server with two (2) assigned subdomains, which I will call **moodle.myorganization.com.ve** and **jupyter.myorganization.com.ve**. For this I have created two Virtual host, one for each subdomain, and I have enabled the apache modules: rewrite, proxy, proxy_http, headers and proxy_wstunnel.

## Virtual host Moodle

`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/moodle.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@myorganization.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/moodle
    ServerName moodle.myorganization.com.ve

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/moodle/>
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews +Includes
        AcceptPathInfo On
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/moodle-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/moodle-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

## Virtual host Jupyter

`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/jupyter.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@myorganization.com
    ServerName jupyter.myorganization.com.ve

    <Location "/">
        ProxyPreserveHost on
        ProxyPass         http://localhost:8000/
        ProxyPassReverse  http://localhost:8000/
        RequestHeader     set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
    </Location>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/jupyter-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/jupyter-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I expected that each subdomain would respond to the corresponding service, but bitterly this is not the case.

When I access **jupyter.myorganization.com.ve**, the request is successfully redirected to the internal jupyter service running at **localhost:8000**.

When accessing to **moodle.myorganization.com.ve**, it bypasses the Moodle virtual host and redirects the request to the Jupyter service.

It should be noted that in addition to the subdomains, i have one (1) public IP that through NAT with different ports I redirect traffic to port 80 and 8080 of the server (for test environment).

I have observed in both subdomains that when inhabiting only one virtual host, the behavior is correct.

I have tried to configure different ports for the services: 80 for Moodle and 8080 for Jupyter. And still, i haven't been able to get each subdomain to respond to the correct service.